# Bit-wise alternative

Tags: random, shader, bit-manipulation, operator-keyword

I'm trying to write a shader that needs pseudo-random number generation per pixel - fetching from a texture is just too expensive.

All of the generators I've found use ^, <<, & operators, but the shader model I'm working on doesn't support these. Is there a mathematical equivalent of these operators I can use instead?

For reference, I'm valuing speed over precision.

Thanks!

Comment: It might help to know which integer operators *are* available ?

Answer (score 0):

Of those, the only one I know the mathematical equivalent to is the `<<` operator.  Namely:

> N << X = N * (2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, etc)

e.g.

> N << 5 = N * 32

Simply create a lookup for the value (2 ^ X), and multiply by that value.

The others are going to be more complicated, and will probably require that you write an algorithm to solve them.  I don't think they have any direct mathematical equivalents.

The source code for a C runtime implementation might be useful for that.  Or simply search for algorithms to implement each, such as: [Fast implementation/approximation of pow() function in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347138/fast-implementation-approximation-of-pow-function-in-c-c)