# Fast approximation/implementation of power function in matalb

Tags: matlab

I am able to find similar answer of C/C++ in the following question:
[Fast implementation/approximation of pow() function in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347138/fast-implementation-approximation-of-pow-function-in-c-c)

My code's bottleneck as per profiler is something similar to following code:

```
a=rand(100,1); % a is an array of doubles
b=1.2; % power can be double instead of only integers.
temp=power(a,b); % this line is taking maximum time
```

For my requirement, only first 3-4 digits are significant, so any fast approximation of power will be very useful to me. Any suggestions to do the same.

**More Information:**
this is how I calculated power using exp and log. This has improvement of roughly 50%. Now I need to find approx functions of log and exp and check if that is faster still.

```
      a=rand(1000,1);

tic;
for i=1:100000
    powA=power(a,1.1);
end
toc;
tic;
for i=1:100000
    powB=exp(1.1*log(a));
end
toc;

Elapsed time is 4.098334 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.994894 seconds.
```

Comment: Mathematically, approximation should know the ranges for `a` and `b`, otherwise it is to broad to discuss

Comment: Use `timeit` to time your code.