# Efficient implementation of fixed-point power (pow) function with argument constraints

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, pow, fixed-point

I'm looking for an efficient implementation of the function `pow(a, b)`, where `a` is limited to the interval `(0,1)`, and `b` is `>= 1` (both are real numbers—i.e., not necessarily integers).

If it helps, `b` is not a high number—let's say it is less than 10-20. That would open up the possibility of solving this problem iteratively, with a small number of iterations ~= `b`

The code should work on a 32-bit microcontroller, possibly without a floating-point unit (i.e., using a fixed-point implementation).

How can I implement such a function, optimized for the following constraints? I'm looking for the algorithm itself, so pseudocode is acceptable.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2347138/1679849

Comment: See [Power by squaring for negative exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30962495/2521214) the [log,exp approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18169727/2521214) will work only if you code the [log,exp functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42108287/2521214) but as you can see you can use also power by squaring/rooting

Comment: @r3mainer that does not answer this question as `math.h` does not have fixed point ... You need to code the math functions related to this which the answers in your link does not cover at all. However the links in my last comment should cover them all ....

Comment: @Spektre That wasn't a vote to close this question; I was just linking it to another question that happens to be related. You've been here longer than I have, surely I don't have to explain to you how Stack Overflow works?

Comment: @r3mainer Heh :) I wasn't thinking nor voting about close either ...I just wanted to point out the fact that MCU + Fixed point makes answers you linked unusable unless some 3th party lib is used in which case the power would be implemented there anyway ... OP needs approach without using advanced math operations like `log,exp` as the platform does not have them so if they are used they must be implemented from scratch like in the links I provided ... and btw. from what i see you are here longer than me by 8 months  ...

Comment: @PSz Does this microcontroller have a fairly fast 32-bit multiplier? Does the programming environment support `int64_t` and `uin64_t` (or equivalent 64-bit integer data types)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem as stated by OP is underspecified. What accuracy is needed, what performance is required? As `a` is known to be non-negative, a suitable starting point is to compute a<sup>b</sup> as `exp2 (b * log2 (a))`, with fixed-point implementations for those functions. Based on my experience with fixed-point arithmetic in embedded systems, using an s15.16 fixed-point format is often a good compromise between representable range and accuracy when generic floating-point computation is replaced with fixed-point computation. So I will adopt that here.

The principal choices for implementing `exp2()` and `log2()` in fixed-point are bitwise computation, quadratic interpolation in a table, and polynomial approximation. The latter two benefit from a hardware multiplier that can produce a double-width product, and table-based approaches work best with a cache of several kilobytes. The OP's specification of a microcontroller suggests that resources for both code and data may be limited, and that this is fairly low-end hardware. So the bit-wise approach may be a good starting point, as it requires only a tiny table shared between the two functions. the code size is small as well, in particular when the compiler is directed to optimize for code size (`-Os` with most compilers).

Bit-wise computations for these functions are also known a pseudo-division and pseudo-multiplication and are closely related to the way by which Henry Briggs (1561 – 1630) computed tables logarithms.

For the computation of the logarithm, we chose, by trial and error, from among a sequence of particular factors those, that when multiplied with the function argument, normalize it to unity. For every factor chosen, we add up the corresponding logarithm value stored in a table. The sum then corresponds to the logarithm of the function argument. For the integer portion, we would want to chose 2<sup>i</sup>, i = 1, 2, 4, 8, ... and for the factional part we choose 1+2<sup>-i</sup>, i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...

The algorithm for the exponential is closely related and quite literally the inverse of the logarithm algorithm. From among the sequence of tabulated logarithms for our chosen factors, we pick those that when subtracted from the function argument ultimately reduce it to zero. Starting with unity, we multiply with all the factors whose logarithms we have subtracted in the process. The resulting product corresponds to the result of the exponentiation.

Logarithms of values greater than unity can be computed by applying the algorithm to the reciprocal of the function argument (with negation of the result as appropriate), likewise exponentiation with negative function arguments requires us negate the function argument and compute the reciprocal at the end. So in this aspect the two algorithms are, unsurprisingly, symmetric as well.

The following ISO-C99 code is a straightforward implementation of these two algorithms. Note that this code uses a fixed-point multiplication with rounding. The incremental cost is minimal and it does enhance the accuracy of the overall `pow()` computation.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

/* s15.16 division without rounding */
int32_t fxdiv_s15p16 (int32_t x, int32_t y)
{
    return ((int64_t)x * 65536) / y;
}

/* s15.16 multiplication with rounding */
int32_t fxmul_s15p16 (int32_t x, int32_t y)
{
    int32_t r;
    int64_t t = (int64_t)x * (int64_t)y;
    r = (int32_t)(uint32_t)(((uint64_t)t + (1 << 15)) >> 16);
    return r;
}

/* log2(2**8), ..., log2(2**1), log2(1+2**(-1), ..., log2(1+2**(-16)) */
const uint32_t tab [20] = {0x80000, 0x40000, 0x20000, 0x10000,
                           0x095c1, 0x0526a, 0x02b80, 0x01663,
                           0x00b5d, 0x005b9, 0x002e0, 0x00170, 
                           0x000b8, 0x0005c, 0x0002e, 0x00017, 
                           0x0000b, 0x00006, 0x00003, 0x00001};
const int32_t one_s15p16 = 1 * (1 << 16);
const int32_t neg_fifteen_s15p16 = (-15) * (1 << 16);

int32_t fxlog2_s15p16 (int32_t a)
{
    uint32_t x, y;
    int32_t t, r;

    x = (a > one_s15p16) ? fxdiv_s15p16 (one_s15p16, a) : a;
    y = 0;
    /* process integer bits */
    if ((t = x << 8) < one_s15p16) { x = t; y += tab [0]; }
    if ((t = x << 4) < one_s15p16) { x = t; y += tab [1]; }
    if ((t = x << 2) < one_s15p16) { x = t; y += tab [2]; }
    if ((t = x << 1) < one_s15p16) { x = t; y += tab [3]; }
    /* process fraction bits */
    for (int shift = 1; shift <= 16; shift++) {
        if ((t = x + (x >> shift)) < one_s15p16) { x = t; y += tab[3 + shift]; }
    }
    r = (a > one_s15p16) ? y : (0 - y);
    return r;
}

int32_t fxexp2_s15p16 (int32_t a) 
{
    uint32_t x, y;
    int32_t t, r;

    if (a <= neg_fifteen_s15p16) return 0; // underflow

    x = (a < 0) ? (-a) : (a);
    y = one_s15p16;
    /* process integer bits */
    if ((t = x - tab [0]) >= 0) { x = t; y = y << 8; }
    if ((t = x - tab [1]) >= 0) { x = t; y = y << 4; }
    if ((t = x - tab [2]) >= 0) { x = t; y = y << 2; }
    if ((t = x - tab [3]) >= 0) { x = t; y = y << 1; }
    /* process fractional bits */
    for (int shift = 1; shift <= 16; shift++) {
        if ((t = x - tab [3 + shift]) >= 0) { x = t; y = y + (y >> shift); }
    }
    r = (a < 0) ? fxdiv_s15p16 (one_s15p16, y) : y;
    return r;
}

/* compute a**b for a >= 0 */
int32_t fxpow_s15p16 (int32_t a, int32_t b)
{
    return fxexp2_s15p16 (fxmul_s15p16 (b, fxlog2_s15p16 (a)));
}

double s15p16_to_double (int32_t a)
{
    return a / 65536.0;
}

int32_t double_to_s15p16 (double a)
{
    return ((int32_t)(a * 65536.0 + ((a < 0) ? (-0.5) : 0.5)));
}

int main (void) 
{
    int32_t a = double_to_s15p16 (0.125);
    do {
        int32_t b = double_to_s15p16 (-5);
        do {
            double fa = s15p16_to_double (a);
            double fb = s15p16_to_double (b);
            double reff = pow (fa, fb);
            int32_t res = fxpow_s15p16 (a, b);
            int32_t ref = double_to_s15p16 (reff);
            double fres = s15p16_to_double (res);
            double fref = s15p16_to_double (ref);
            printf ("a=%08x (%15.8e) b=%08x (% 15.8e) res=%08x (% 15.8e) ref=%08x (%15.8e)\n", 
                    a, fa, b, fb, res, fres, ref, fref);
            b += double_to_s15p16 (0.5);
        } while (b <= double_to_s15p16 (6));
        printf ("\n");
        a += double_to_s15p16 (0.125);
    } while (a <= double_to_s15p16 (1.0));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

For processors with a reasonable amount cache and a fast integer multiply, we can use quadratic interpolation in tables for very accurate and fast computation on `log2()` and `exp2()`. To do so, we make use of a pseudo-floating-point representation where the argument `x` = 2<sup>i</sup>(1+*f*), with *f* in [0,1). The fraction `f` is normalized using the full word size of 32 bits. For the logarithm, we tabulate log2(1+*f*) which falls into [0, 1). For the exponential we tabulate exp2(*f*)-1 which also falls into [0,1). Obviously we need to add 1 to the result of the table interpolation.

For a quadratic interpolation we need a total of three table entries through which we fit a parabola, whose coefficients `a` and `b` can be computed on the fly. The difference between the function argument and the closest node as *dx*, we can then add a(*dx*)<sup>2</sup>+b(*dx*) to the corresponding table entry for interpolation. The need for three consecutive table entries to fit the parabola also means we need to tabulate two additional values beyond our primary interpolation interval. The inaccuracy due to the use of fixed-point arithmetic for intermediate computation can partially be compensated by adding a rounding constant at the end, which needs to be determined experimentally.

```c
    /* for i = 0 to 65: log2 (1 + i/64) * 2**31 */
    uint32_t logTab [66] =
    {
        0x00000000, 0x02dcf2d1, 0x05aeb4dd, 0x08759c50, 
        0x0b31fb7d, 0x0de42120, 0x108c588d, 0x132ae9e2, 
        0x15c01a3a, 0x184c2bd0, 0x1acf5e2e, 0x1d49ee4c, 
        0x1fbc16b9, 0x22260fb6, 0x24880f56, 0x26e2499d, 
        0x2934f098, 0x2b803474, 0x2dc4439b, 0x30014ac6, 
        0x32377512, 0x3466ec15, 0x368fd7ee, 0x38b25f5a, 
        0x3acea7c0, 0x3ce4d544, 0x3ef50ad2, 0x40ff6a2e, 
        0x43041403, 0x450327eb, 0x46fcc47a, 0x48f10751, 
        0x4ae00d1d, 0x4cc9f1ab, 0x4eaecfeb, 0x508ec1fa, 
        0x5269e12f, 0x5440461c, 0x5612089a, 0x57df3fd0, 
        0x59a80239, 0x5b6c65aa, 0x5d2c7f59, 0x5ee863e5, 
        0x60a02757, 0x6253dd2c, 0x64039858, 0x65af6b4b, 
        0x675767f5, 0x68fb9fce, 0x6a9c23d6, 0x6c39049b, 
        0x6dd2523d, 0x6f681c73, 0x70fa728c, 0x72896373, 
        0x7414fdb5, 0x759d4f81, 0x772266ad, 0x78a450b8, 
        0x7a231ace, 0x7b9ed1c7, 0x7d17822f, 0x7e8d3846, 
        0x80000000, 0x816fe50b
    };
    
    /* for i = 0 to 129: exp2 ((i/128) - 1) * 2**31 */
    uint32_t expTab [130] =
    {
        0x00000000, 0x00b1ed50, 0x0164d1f4, 0x0218af43,
        0x02cd8699, 0x0383594f, 0x043a28c4, 0x04f1f656,
        0x05aac368, 0x0664915c, 0x071f6197, 0x07db3580,
        0x08980e81, 0x0955ee03, 0x0a14d575, 0x0ad4c645,
        0x0b95c1e4, 0x0c57c9c4, 0x0d1adf5b, 0x0ddf0420,
        0x0ea4398b, 0x0f6a8118, 0x1031dc43, 0x10fa4c8c,
        0x11c3d374, 0x128e727e, 0x135a2b2f, 0x1426ff10,
        0x14f4efa9, 0x15c3fe87, 0x16942d37, 0x17657d4a,
        0x1837f052, 0x190b87e2, 0x19e04593, 0x1ab62afd,
        0x1b8d39ba, 0x1c657368, 0x1d3ed9a7, 0x1e196e19,
        0x1ef53261, 0x1fd22825, 0x20b05110, 0x218faecb,
        0x22704303, 0x23520f69, 0x243515ae, 0x25195787,
        0x25fed6aa, 0x26e594d0, 0x27cd93b5, 0x28b6d516,
        0x29a15ab5, 0x2a8d2653, 0x2b7a39b6, 0x2c6896a5,
        0x2d583eea, 0x2e493453, 0x2f3b78ad, 0x302f0dcc,
        0x3123f582, 0x321a31a6, 0x3311c413, 0x340aaea2,
        0x3504f334, 0x360093a8, 0x36fd91e3, 0x37fbefcb,
        0x38fbaf47, 0x39fcd245, 0x3aff5ab2, 0x3c034a7f,
        0x3d08a39f, 0x3e0f680a, 0x3f1799b6, 0x40213aa2,
        0x412c4cca, 0x4238d231, 0x4346ccda, 0x44563ecc,
        0x45672a11, 0x467990b6, 0x478d74c9, 0x48a2d85d,
        0x49b9bd86, 0x4ad2265e, 0x4bec14ff, 0x4d078b86,
        0x4e248c15, 0x4f4318cf, 0x506333db, 0x5184df62,
        0x52a81d92, 0x53ccf09a, 0x54f35aac, 0x561b5dff,
        0x5744fccb, 0x5870394c, 0x599d15c2, 0x5acb946f,
        0x5bfbb798, 0x5d2d8185, 0x5e60f482, 0x5f9612df,
        0x60ccdeec, 0x62055b00, 0x633f8973, 0x647b6ca0,
        0x65b906e7, 0x66f85aab, 0x68396a50, 0x697c3840,
        0x6ac0c6e8, 0x6c0718b6, 0x6d4f301f, 0x6e990f98,
        0x6fe4b99c, 0x713230a8, 0x7281773c, 0x73d28fde,
        0x75257d15, 0x767a416c, 0x77d0df73, 0x792959bb,
        0x7a83b2db, 0x7bdfed6d, 0x7d3e0c0d, 0x7e9e115c,
        0x80000000, 0x8163daa0,
    };
    
    uint8_t clz_tab[32] = {
        31, 22, 30, 21, 18, 10, 29,  2, 20, 17, 15, 13, 9,  6, 28, 1,
        23, 19, 11,  3, 16, 14,  7, 24, 12,  4,  8, 25, 5, 26, 27, 0};
    
    /* count leading zeros; this is a machine instruction on many architectures */
    int32_t clz (uint32_t a)
    {
        a |= a >> 16;
        a |= a >> 8;
        a |= a >> 4;
        a |= a >> 2;
        a |= a >> 1;
        return clz_tab [0x07c4acdd * a >> 27];
    }
    
    int32_t fxlog2_s15p16 (int32_t arg)
    {
        int32_t lz, f1, f2, dx, a, b, approx;
        uint32_t t, idx, x = arg;
        lz = clz (x);
        /* shift off integer bits and normalize fraction 0 <= f <= 1 */
        t = x << (lz + 1);
        /* index table of values log2 (1 + f) using 6 msbs of fraction */
        idx = (unsigned)t >> (32 - 6);
        /* difference between argument and smallest sampling point */
        dx = t - (idx << (32 - 6));
        /* fit parabola through closest three sampling points; find coeffs a, b */
        f1 = (logTab[idx+1] - logTab[idx]);
        f2 = (logTab[idx+2] - logTab[idx]);
        a = f2 - (f1 << 1);
        b = (f1 << 1) - a;
        /* find function value for argument by computing ((a*dx+b)*dx) */
        approx = (int32_t)((((int64_t)a)*dx) >> (32 - 6)) + b;
        approx = (int32_t)((((int64_t)approx)*dx) >> (32 - 6 + 1));
        /* compute fraction result; add experimentally determined rounding constant */
        approx = logTab[idx] + approx + 0x410d;
        /* combine integer and fractional parts of result */
        approx = ((15 - lz) << 16) + (((uint32_t)approx) >> 15);
        return approx;
    }
    
    int32_t fxexp2_s15p16 (int32_t x)
    {
        int32_t f1, f2, dx, a, b, approx, idx, i, f;
    
        /* extract integer portion; 2**i is realized as a shift at the end */
        i = (x >> 16);
        /* extract fraction f so we can compute 2**(f)-1, 0 <= f < 1 */
        f = x & 0xffff;
        /* index table of values exp2 (f) - 1 using 7 msbs of fraction */
        idx = (uint32_t)f >> (16 - 7);
        /* difference between argument and next smaller sampling point */
        dx = f - (idx << (16 - 7));
        /* fit parabola through closest three sampling point; find coeffs a,b */
        f1 = (expTab[idx+1] - expTab[idx]);
        f2 = (expTab[idx+2] - expTab[idx]);
        a = f2 - (f1 << 1);
        b = (f1 << 1) - a;
        /* find function value for argument by computing ((a*dx+b)*dx) */
        approx = (int32_t)((((int64_t)a)*dx) >> (16 - 7)) + b;
        approx = (int32_t)((((int64_t)approx)*dx) >> (16 - 7 + 1));
        /* combine integer and fractional parts of result; add 1.0 and experimentally determined rounding constant */
        approx = (((expTab[idx] + (unsigned)approx + 0x80000012U) >> (14 - i)) + 1) >> 1;
        /* Handle underflow to 0 */
        approx = ((i < -16) ? 0 : approx);
        return approx;
    }
```

Finally, on platforms for which data storage is limited but which provide a very fast integer multiplier, one can use a polynomial approximation of the minimax kind, i.e. one which minimizes the maximum error. The code for this will be similar to the table-based method, except that the two core approximations, log2(1+f) and exp2(f)-1 for f in [0,1), are computed via polynomials instead of tables. For maximum accuracy and code efficiency, we would want to represent the coefficients as unsigned pure fractions, that is, by using a u0.32 fixed-point format. In the case of log2(), the leading coefficient is ~= 1.44, so will not fit into this format. However, this is easily solved by splitting this coefficient into two parts, 1 and 0.44. For fixed-point computation evaluation via Horner scheme is typically not necessary, and best use of a pipelined multiplier plus an increase in instruction-level parallelism can be achieved with an Estrin-like scheme, as pointed out in

Claude-Pierre Jeannerod, Jingyan Jourdan-Lu, "Simultaneous floating-point sine and cosine for VLIW integer processors". In *23<sup>rd</sup> IEEE International Conference on Application-Specific Systems, Architectures and Processors*, July 2012, pp. 69-76 ([preprint online](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00672327/))

```c
    /* a single instruction in many 32-bit architectures */
    uint32_t umul32hi (uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
    {
        return (uint32_t)(((uint64_t)a * b) >> 32);
    }
    
    uint8_t clz_tab[32] = {
            31, 22, 30, 21, 18, 10, 29,  2, 20, 17, 15, 13, 9,  6, 28, 1,
            23, 19, 11,  3, 16, 14,  7, 24, 12,  4,  8, 25, 5, 26, 27, 0};
    
    /* count leading zeros; this is a machine instruction on many architectures */
    int32_t clz (uint32_t a)
    {
        a |= a >> 16;
        a |= a >> 8;
        a |= a >> 4;
        a |= a >> 2;
        a |= a >> 1;
        return clz_tab [0x07c4acdd * a >> 27];
    }
    
    /* compute log2() with s15.16 fixed-point argument and result */
    int32_t fxlog2_s15p16 (int32_t arg)
    {
        const uint32_t a0 = (uint32_t)((1.44269476063 - 1)* (1LL << 32) + 0.5);
        const uint32_t a1 = (uint32_t)(7.2131008654833e-1 * (1LL << 32) + 0.5);
        const uint32_t a2 = (uint32_t)(4.8006370104849e-1 * (1LL << 32) + 0.5);
        const uint32_t a3 = (uint32_t)(3.5339481476694e-1 * (1LL << 32) + 0.5);
        const uint32_t a4 = (uint32_t)(2.5600972794928e-1 * (1LL << 32) + 0.5);
        const uint32_t a5 = (uint32_t)(1.5535182948224e-1 * (1LL << 32) + 0.5);
        const uint32_t a6 = (uint32_t)(6.3607925549150e-2 * (1LL << 32) + 0.5);
        const uint32_t a7 = (uint32_t)(1.2319647939876e-2 * (1LL << 32) + 0.5);
        int32_t lz;
        uint32_t approx, h, m, l, z, y, x = arg;
        lz = clz (x);
        /* shift off integer bits and normalize fraction 0 <= f <= 1 */
        x = x << (lz + 1);
        y = umul32hi (x, x); // f**2
        z = umul32hi (y, y); // f**4
        /* evaluate minimax polynomial to compute log2(1+f) */
        h = a0 - umul32hi (a1, x);
        m = umul32hi (a2 - umul32hi (a3, x), y);
        l = umul32hi (a4 - umul32hi (a5, x) + umul32hi(a6 - umul32hi(a7, x), y), z);
        approx = x + umul32hi (x, h + m + l);
        /* combine integer and fractional parts of result; round result */
        approx = ((15 - lz) << 16) + ((((approx) >> 15) + 1) >> 1);
        return approx;
    }

    /* compute exp2() with s15.16 fixed-point argument and result */
    int32_t fxexp2_s15p16 (int32_t arg)
    {
        const uint32_t a0 = (uint32_t)(6.9314718107e-1 * (1LL << 32) + 0.5);
        const uint32_t a1 = (uint32_t)(2.4022648809e-1 * (1LL << 32) + 0.5);
        const uint32_t a2 = (uint32_t)(5.5504413787e-2 * (1LL << 32) + 0.5);
        const uint32_t a3 = (uint32_t)(9.6162736882e-3 * (1LL << 32) + 0.5);
        const uint32_t a4 = (uint32_t)(1.3386828359e-3 * (1LL << 32) + 0.5);
        const uint32_t a5 = (uint32_t)(1.4629773796e-4 * (1LL << 32) + 0.5);
        const uint32_t a6 = (uint32_t)(2.0663021132e-5 * (1LL << 32) + 0.5);
        int32_t i;
        uint32_t approx, h, m, l, s, q, f, x = arg;
    
        /* extract integer portion; 2**i is realized as a shift at the end */
        i = ((x >> 16) ^ 0x8000) - 0x8000;
        /* extract and normalize fraction f to compute 2**(f)-1, 0 <= f < 1 */
        f = x << 16;
        /* evaluate minimax polynomial to compute exp2(f)-1 */
        s = umul32hi (f, f); // f**2
        q = umul32hi (s, s); // f**4
        h = a0 + umul32hi (a1, f);
        m = umul32hi (a2 + umul32hi (a3, f), s);
        l = umul32hi (a4 + umul32hi (a5, f) + umul32hi (a6, s), q);
        approx = umul32hi (f, h + m + l);
        /* combine integer and fractional parts of result; round result */
        approx = ((approx >> (15 - i)) + (0x80000000 >> (14 - i)) + 1) >> 1;
        /* handle underflow to 0 */
        approx = ((i < -16) ? 0 : approx);
        return approx;
    }
```